# Updating data in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a registration page which spans across multiple pages which collects a users data, such as address, DOB, name, etc.

On each page i have some code which runs which updates individual fields in a document within firebase. for example.

```
SECTION 1:
               onPressed: () async {
                      if(_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(
                          _currentPinCode ?? userData.pinCode,
                        );
                      }
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.signup4);
                  }
```

I have a file called database.dart which handles the database queries. In here i have a function called updateUserData with fields which i wish to update in my firebase document. See Below:

```
SECTION 2:
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService ({ this.uid });

  final CollectionReference userCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('users');
  
  Future updateUserData(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName,
                        String dateOfBirth, String phone, int pinCode, String addressLn1,
                        String addressLn2, String city, String postCode, String country,
  ) async {
    return await userCollection.document(uid).setData({
      'firstName': firstName,
      'middleName' : middleName,
      'lastName' : lastName,
      'dateOfBirth' : dateOfBirth,
      'phone' : phone,
      'pinCode' : pinCode,
      'addressLn1' : addressLn1,
      'addressLn2' : addressLn2,
      'city' : city,
      'postCode' : postCode,
      'country' : country,
    });
  }
```

When the code in SECTION 1 runs, it is of course missing all the parameters in SECTION 2, and therefore fail.

I would like to know whats the best way to update the firebase document, when data is on multiple pages within the app. Is it better to collect all the data in a Map, with the context of the Map spanning multiple pages, or is it better to update the database as each page is completed and if so what would be the best way to do that.

I know it's an odd question, but a little stuck and any help would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Collecting everything in a `Map` would be better as it would reduce the number of writes that you would have to do.

Comment: what would be the best way to do that, do you have an example please.

Comment: I would recommend you try it yourself first. Instantiate a `Map` on the first page and pass it through to the last, adding data from each page. On the last page, use the `Map` to set the data in firestore.